# Is there a sphinx domain for R?

Tags: r, python-sphinx

I want to document R-code with sphinx. 
As I understood from this page https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/2.0/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#more-domains it would be easiest if there was a domain already defined for R but I cannot find any.
Hence my question: Is there a sphinx-domain for R?